# Is there any methods to accelerate RSA?

Tags: openssl, rsa

We can use Intel's AESNI to accelerate AES encoding/decoding. But in a SSL session, before AES we have to use RSA to exchange keys; are there any methods to accelerate RSA also?

Answer (score 1):

Intel also provided similar optimization on RSA and SHA. We can find the source here : 
https://www.openssl.org/contrib/

file name : intel-accel-1.5.tar.gz

I think for the latest version of openssl, intel already contributed their code to the repository.